# Why is a question upvote less rep than an answer upvote when it is harder to get?

Tags: discussion

Question upvote = 5 reputation points

Answer upvote = 10 reputation points

But we all know answers are upvoted much more readily than questions.

So why does a question upvote only get 5 reputation points?

Because it is harder to get I think it should get 10 reputation points also.

I appreciate "a question is receiving" and "an answer is giving" and that should be taken into account and reduce the reputation points value of a question upvote. However, given that a question upvote is much harder to get, I feel that there is no need for a reputation points reduction.

Consider these maths, which assumes that an answer will get double the number of upvotes (which in my experience is roughly correct)...

Question is asked which receives 20 upvotes = 5 * 20 = 100 reputation points

Answer is received which receives 40 upvotes = 10 * 40 = 400 reputation points

So the answer, all things being equal, scores four times more than the question. While I could understand the answer scoring double, scoring four times more is too much!

Recommendation...

Question upvote = 10 reputation points

Answer upvote = 10 reputation points

Thoughts?

Comment: It used to be like that, then they changed it, to encourage people to answer more.

Comment: `BUT we all know answers are upvoted much more readily than questions.`  Do you have supporting evidence?  I see plenty of upvoted questions without answers and answers with lower scores than the question.  I don't have evidence to the contrary mind you, but I don't think your statement is a fair assumption

Comment: my highest answers ... 27, 21, 15 ... highest questions ... 11, 5, 5

Comment: A sample size of 1 doesn't exactly establish a pattern. Lots of people vote freely on *all* questions, but are more reluctant to vote on answers because they aren't sure whether the answer is correct or technically accurate, generally limiting themselves to voting only on answers for only technologies with which they are familiar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **Note:** This answer is obsolete since November 2019, when the change was reverted: [upvotes on questions gives 10 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/).

---

It used to be 10 reputation per upvote period, But that was changed in March 2010 following a discussion on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced).

Jeff Atwood gives the following reasons:

> While we value good questions (and asking a great question is
> absolutely an art), we want to explicitly encourage people to provide
> the best possible answers. Without people interested in providing good
> answers, the questions are moot. We know that answers have more
> intrinsic value than questions, and the reputation balance should
> reflect that.

and

> The question asker already enjoys a substantial benefit beyond
> reputation gain from upvotes on their question -- namely, they get
> great answers to their question! Thus, the asker shouldn't need as
> much reputation gain.

and

> There are a few users who ask hundreds, sometimes even thousands of
> questions. Over time, these users generate a fairly sizable reputation
> entirely through the tiny trickle of upvotes gained by these
> questions. In a sense, we want to discourage question asking a little
> bit, and make sure that people who ask questions are doing it for the
> right reasons and not to generate reputation.

[(source)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/)

These reasons are in effect today still. Especially today. Answers are what makes this site work, and while you can compose a question to host a incredibly detailed and good answer, the other way around it is much harder.

Comment: And back! https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/

Answer (score 6):

Question upvotes used to give 10 reputation, but as a result of [a discussion in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced), it was reduced to 5.

> How about if **question upvotes** were only worth +5 rep instead of
>   +10? And this was applied retroactively? (answer upvotes would be unchanged from the current behavior, so this would be question
>   specific.)
>
> This seems to be a better solution to the particular ["shore, there is
>   always gold"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33398/the-surest-way-to-gain-lots-of-reputation-on-stack-overflow-ask-questions/33407#33407) problem  without all the rather serious negative
>   repercussions of increasing the punitive value and/or cost of
>   downvotes across the board.